# Better image quality on Samsung Smart TV with HDMI wanted

Tags: display, mac-mini, hdmi, resolution

I have connected my Mac Mini A1347 to my Samsung Smart TV UE32ES6530 using a HDMI cable. This works out of the box but the display is rather ugly. I already changed the resolution to a lower value using this dialog but for my taste the display is still ugly. What else can I do?

[image: SAMSUNG display]

1080p and 1080i render the font hard to read. My current choice is 1366 * 768.

Comment: Did you try "Standard für Monitor"??

Comment: Did you try changing the Underscan?